# Twitter Rest API thrown exception

Tags: twitter-oauth

I have created the sample OAUTH project with Twitter account. While I am getting data Via rest API "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json" its thrown exception like "error: Your credential not allow to access this resource; error code :220"

NOTE:
I have get access token using PIN based access token method.
I have set the application permission as read and write access.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what other API requests that do work or which type of authentication you are using, one can only guess what your particular issue is. My first question would be are you authenticating as a user or as an application? In other words, are you using OAuth 1 or OAuth 2? The former is required for `statuses/home_timeline`  requests.

Comment: Hi Jonas,I am using the OAuth1 with user based authentication type. I got access token response like "oauth_token=9480810086*****-Pk9yA**********6ixGFkFxSdBbJ&oauth_token_secret=Sfwk32pyCd9yeLzGD**********SxgsuvSeaUkqedE&user_id=9480810086******&screen_name=Sssc&x_auth_expires=0" and when i am trying to get the data from any REST API means it shown errors some times "Invalid or Expired token".

Comment: HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
           var requestUserTimeline = new HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get, contactsApiUrl);
                 requestUserTimeline.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + parameter.AccessToken);
                    HttpResponseMessage responseUserTimeLine = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestUserTimeline);
               httpClient.CancelPendingRequests();
        json = await responseUserTimeLine.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                       This is the code i am using for getting data from REST API.

Comment: You are setting the the "Authorization" header to "Bearer" + access token. This is OAuth 2. You must use OAuth 1to authenticate as a user in order to request that user's home timeline.There are C# OAutth libraries for this. Here is an example not using a library so you can see what is involved - https://gist.github.com/geduldig/6553364